# Why does the overflow of string's buffer result in the weird behavior in C?

Tags: arrays, c, string, loops, memory

I just started learning C programming language and was testing out some control flow, stdio functionalities.

This is my code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  char b[5], c[5];

  char arr[2][5];

  printf("Enter the first string: ");
  scanf("%s", b);
  printf("b -> %s\n", b);
  strcpy(arr[0], b);
  printf("arr[0] -> %s\n", arr[0]);

  printf("Enter the second string: ");
  scanf("%s", c);
  printf("c -> %s\n", c);
  strcpy(arr[1], c);
  printf("arr[1] -> %s\n", arr[1]);

  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    printf("%d -> %s\n", i, arr[i]);
  }

  if (strcmp(b, c) == 0) {
    printf("Strings %s and %s are the same.\n", b, c);
  } else {
    printf("Strings %s and %s are not the same.\n", b, c);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The problem I got was with the buffer overflow, aka, when I entered the string with 5 characters, initially it displayed it correctly, but near the end of the program, results became messed up.

printing the variables before the `for` loop do the job correctly (let's say I provide `somew` as an input string for both):

```bash
b -> somew
arr[0] -> somew

c -> somew
arr[1] -> somew
```

But then, in the `for` loop, the printed result is:

```bash
0 -> somewsomew
1 -> somew
```

And finally, the last comparison prints:

```bash
Strings     and somew are not the same.
```

I read that the strings in `C` are `null terminated` and so providing a word of length 4, for example, fixes this issue, I just want to know how for example in the `for` loop I got the result `0 -> somewsomew` and why was the variable `b` empty for the last comparison.

Comment: There is no real explanation. Writing out-of-bounds is undefined, and *anything* can happen.